# Getting "invalid_payload" and 400 response when trying to send data to a slack channel through Postman

Tags: postman, slack-api

I'm using postman to trigger a message using the slack channel's incoming webhook url. I tried the following curl and it works:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/T026NT2D4/B02UM3G1D35' \
--header 'Content-type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"text":"Hello world"}'
```

I need to send aws S3's presigned URL to this channel but no matter how I try sending the data, I always get **invalid_payload** as the response. I tried sending it as Json message, Raw text and even tried x-www-form-urlencoded. Nothing seems to work.

I need some implementation example for this. Also, I'll be using spring boot to generate and send the message, so any resources on beautifying the message would be really helpful.

I've seen examples where the slack channel has some text and "more" option, which, upon clicking downloads a file(I'm assuming this "more" is a hyperlink of the presigned URL)

**EDIT**:

I was trying out a few more stuff. When I send the Json with only one field and specifically naming that filed "text", I'm able to send the message.

So my payload looked liked this:

```
{
  "text": "*Presigned URL*"
}
```

The headers had Content-type as application/json.

Even if I changed "text" to "Message" I'm getting a 400 response. Is that what no_text means? that there is no "text" field in the payload

Answer (score 0):

Just putting it here in case someone needs this.

That is the case, a "text" field should be there in the json message.

[Link to slack guide](https://app.slack.com/block-kit-builder/T026NT2D4#%7B%22blocks%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22section%22%2C%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22mrkdwn%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Hello%2C%20Assistant%20to%20the%20Regional%20Manager%20Dwight%21%20%2AMichael%20Scott%2A%20wants%20to%20know%20where%20you%27d%20like%20to%20take%20the%20Paper%20Company%20investors%20to%20dinner%20tonight.%5Cn%5Cn%20%2APlease%20select%20a%20restaurant%3A%2A%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22divider%22%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22section%22%2C%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22mrkdwn%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22%2AFarmhouse%20Thai%20Cuisine%2A%5Cn%3Astar%3A%3Astar%3A%3Astar%3A%3Astar%3A%201528%20reviews%5Cn%20They%20do%20have%20some%20vegan%20options%2C%20like%20the%20roti%20and%20curry%2C%20plus%20they%20have%20a%20ton%20of%20salad%20stuff%20and%20noodles%20can%20be%20ordered%20without%20meat%21%21%20They%20have%20something%20for%20everyone%20here%22%7D%2C%22accessory%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22image%22%2C%22image_url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fs3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com%2Fbphoto%2Fc7ed05m9lC2EmA3Aruue7A%2Fo.jpg%22%2C%22alt_text%22%3A%22alt%20text%20for%20image%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22section%22%2C%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22mrkdwn%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22%2AKin%20Khao%2A%5Cn%3Astar%3A%3Astar%3A%3Astar%3A%3Astar%3A%201638%20reviews%5Cn%20The%20sticky%20rice%20also%20goes%20wonderfully%20with%20the%20caramelized%20pork%20belly%2C%20which%20is%20absolutely%20melt-in-your-mouth%20and%20so%20soft.%22%7D%2C%22accessory%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22image%22%2C%22image_url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fs3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com%2Fbphoto%2Fkorel-1YjNtFtJlMTaC26A%2Fo.jpg%22%2C%22alt_text%22%3A%22alt%20text%20for%20image%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22section%22%2C%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22mrkdwn%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22%2ALer%20Ros%2A%5Cn%3Astar%3A%3Astar%3A%3Astar%3A%3Astar%3A%202082%20reviews%5Cn%20I%20would%20really%20recommend%20the%20%20Yum%20Koh%20Moo%20Yang%20-%20Spicy%20lime%20dressing%20and%20roasted%20quick%20marinated%20pork%20shoulder%2C%20basil%20leaves%2C%20chili%20%26%20rice%20powder.%22%7D%2C%22accessory%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22image%22%2C%22image_url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fs3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com%2Fbphoto%2FDawwNigKJ2ckPeDeDM7jAg%2Fo.jpg%22%2C%22alt_text%22%3A%22alt%20text%20for%20image%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22divider%22%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22actions%22%2C%22elements%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22button%22%2C%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Farmhouse%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22value%22%3A%22click_me_123%22%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22button%22%2C%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Kin%20Khao%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22value%22%3A%22click_me_123%22%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22button%22%2C%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Ler%20Ros%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22value%22%3A%22click_me_123%22%7D%5D%7D%5D%7D)

Found this implementation in case anyone wants to use slack SDK in spring boot :  [Implementation Link](https://medium.com/cloud-native-the-gathering/how-to-send-formatted-slack-message-blocks-via-the-java-slack-sdk-client-api-3fc9edb1aa98)